# How to query a value from json array type column from a table in sql server?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2012, open-json, json-value

I have a table with a single row of data which has a nvarchar(MAX) type column, lets name the column as json_column and the values of the column are like below:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "john",
        "num": "123"
    },
    {
        "name": "peter",
        "num": "345"
    },
    {
        "name": "donald",
        "num": "789"
    },
 ]
}
```

Now how can I get the value of num where name is passed as input to a where clause or query?

My query should return only the value of num.

For example: lets say I need the value of num where name is 'john' and the query should return me 123.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer and the query can be written as follows:

```
SELECT OPENJSON((SELECT json_column From json_column_table),'$.data')
WITH 
(
 name nvarchar(100) '$.name',
 num  nvarchar(100) '$.num'
)
WHERE name='john';
```